# Align header and textarea inline but fill window width

Tags: html, css, alignment, textarea

One is a header, another one is a textarea. If I don't use "display: inline-block" it puts them on 2 separate lines and the textarea properly fills to the width of the window and resizes if the window size changes. However, I want them to be inline but when I add the "display: inline-block", the textarea no longer fills to the width of the page.

Here is the code that I currently have.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block" id="element1">
    <h4>Description</h4>
</div>
    
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: text-top;" id="element2">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly="readonly" style="width:100%">body</textarea>
</div>
```

This is a screenshot of what it produces. 
[Current Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5d1l.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I added a wrapper having `display: flex` and set the 2:nd child (last `div`) to `flex: 1`, which makes it fill the remaining space.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.wrapper div:last-child textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="element1">
    Description
  </div>
  <div id="element2">
    <textarea rows="4" readonly="readonly">body</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if the `div`'s were there only as an attempt to align them, you can drop them all together

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.wrapper textarea {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Description</span>
  <textarea rows="4" readonly="readonly">body</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your header and div,
Then add external css to your textarea

```
div{
      display:block;
      margin:auto;
      position:static;
      }

 textarea{
                 box-sizing:border-box;
                 display:block;
                 margin:auto;
                 width:100%;
                 }
  textarea::before{
                                content:"Description";
                                vertical-align:top;
                               }
```